# Transformer initialize twice in pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am recently learning gridsearchCV with pipeline. However, i am pretty sure my pipeline model has no issues as shown below.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from Transformers import TextTransformer, ColumnExtractor

a = TextTransformer('description', max_features=300)
b = TextTransformer('features', max_features=300)
c = TextTransformer('street_address', max_features = 300)
d = TextTransformer('display_address', max_features = 300)
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('test', FeatureUnion
         ([
            ('description', a ), # can pass in either a pipeline
            #('features', b),
            #('street', c),
            #('display', d),
            #('lat_long', ColumnExtractor(['latitude', 'longitude']))
        ])),
    ('clf', SVC())
    ])
```

Using the same piece of code :

This works

```
pipeline.fit(df,df['interest_level'])
pipeline.predict(df)
```

This fails:

```
pg = {'clf__C': [0.1,0.2]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = pg)
grid.fit(df, df['interest_level'])
```

I am confident it is not my pipeline issue as purely calling fit and predict on the pipeline works fine. But using gridsearch it throws up a value error. This does not make any sense to me. I am pretty sure i am using the api correctly as well

Update Bug:

This code will fail

```
Transformer class 
class TextTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, column, max_features):
        self.tfidfVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, stop_words='english',
                                               tokenizer=self._custom_tokenizer, analyzer='word',
                                               max_features=max_features)
        self._vectorizer = None
        self._column = column
```

However, if i were to change the init to this.  It will work

```
class TextTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, column, max_features):
        print 'column', column
        print 'init'
        self.tfidfVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, stop_words='english',
                                               tokenizer=self._custom_tokenizer, analyzer='word',
                                               max_features=max_features)
        self._vectorizer = None
        self._column = 'description'
```

What was the problem was that the TextTransformer class was initizalized twice. And it happened that the second time the parameter wasnt passed to column which resulted in the error

Transformer class

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import nltk


class TextTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, column, max_features):
        self.tfidfVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, stop_words='english',
                                               tokenizer=self._custom_tokenizer, analyzer='word',
                                               max_features=max_features)
        self._vectorizer = None
        self._column = column

    def _custom_tokenizer(self, string):
        # string = re.sub('^[\w]', '', string)
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
        cleaned = [x if not x.isdigit() else '_NUM_' for x in tokens]
        return [str(x.encode('utf-8')) for x in cleaned if (x.isalpha() or x == '_NUM_')]

    def _clean_html_tags(self, content):
        return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml').text

    def fit(self, df, y = None):
        if self._column == 'features':
            df[self._column] = df[self._column].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
        self._vectorizer = self.tfidfVectorizer.fit(df[self._column].apply(self._clean_html_tags))
        return self

    def transform(self, df, y = None):
        if self._column == 'features':
            df[self._column] = df[self._column].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
        return self._vectorizer.transform(df[self._column])

class ColumnExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, cols):
        self.cols = cols

    def transform(self, df, y = None):
        return df[self.cols].values

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
```

Stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-437510c295ef> in <module>()
     23     ('clf',SVC(probability = True))
     24     ])
---> 25 scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, df[['description','features','street_address','display_address','latitude', 'longitude']], df['interest_level'], cv=2)
     26 
     27 for train_index, test_index in skf.split(df, df['interest_level']):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    138                                               train, test, verbose, None,
    139                                               fit_params)
--> 140                       for train, test in cv_iter)
    141     return np.array(scores)[:, 0]
    142 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    606                 return False
    607             else:
--> 608                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    609                 return True
    610 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    569         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    570         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 571         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    572         self._jobs.append(job)
    573 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    107     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    108         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 109         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    110         if callback:
    111             callback(result)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    324         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    325         # arguments in memory
--> 326         self.results = batch()
    327 
    328     def get(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    236             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    237         else:
--> 238             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    239 
    240     except Exception as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    266             This estimator
    267         """
--> 268         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    269         if self._final_estimator is not None:
    270             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    232                 pass
    233             elif hasattr(transform, "fit_transform"):
--> 234                 Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
    235             else:
    236                 Xt = transform.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name]) \

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    732             delayed(_fit_transform_one)(trans, name, weight, X, y,
    733                                         **fit_params)
--> 734             for name, trans, weight in self._iter())
    735 
    736         if not result:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    606                 return False
    607             else:
--> 608                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    609                 return True
    610 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    569         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    570         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 571         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    572         self._jobs.append(job)
    573 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    107     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    108         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 109         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    110         if callback:
    111             callback(result)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    324         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    325         # arguments in memory
--> 326         self.results = batch()
    327 
    328     def get(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, name, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
    575                        **fit_params):
    576     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 577         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    578     else:
    579         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    495         else:
    496             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 497             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    498 
    499 

<ipython-input-38-8d6ae99b7816> in fit(self, df, y)
     29         if self._column == 'features':
     30             df[self._column] = df[self._column].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
---> 31         self._vectorizer = self.tfidfVectorizer.fit(df[self._column].apply(self._clean_html_tags))
     32         return self
     33 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060 
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067 
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3550                         loc = indexer.item()
   3551                     else:
-> 3552                         raise ValueError("cannot label index with a null key")
   3553 
   3554             return self.iget(loc, fastpath=fastpath)

ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
```

Comment: Hey, any chance you can put in a dataset that re-creates the issue? I get the feeling that your error might be coming from this part of the code: pipeline.fit(df,df['interest_level']) where both your X and y will include the 'interest_level' variable. Hard to tell though

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet but won't the pipeline only take the relevant columns that I put in? Yes the original df contains the interest level column

Comment: Ahhh @aceminer - I see what you're saying. I think I just misread it. Is there any chance you can attach some dummy data that recreates the error?

Comment: @plumbus_bouquet I have updated my question. It seems this is a weird behaviour. I narrowed down the bug to this

Comment: Cheers for the update. It kinda sounds like you know more about the issue than I do, and I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of sklearn (sorry). All I can recommend is that if you've got a work around then use it, and maybe open an issue on the sklearn github repo

Comment: Please provide full stack trace and also full code for TextTransformer.

Comment: @VivekKumar Added in the stack trace as well as the full code for texttransformer

Comment: You should put a print statement in the TextTransformer fit() method to print the value of `self._column`

Comment: @VivekKumar I did. It printed None. Which was weird

Comment: Try initializing as TextTransformer(column='description', max_features=300)

Comment: @aceminer So, did you solve the problem?

Comment: @VivekKumar yet to try will keep u updated thx.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case someone stumbles across this:

The problem is in the `TextTransformer` class. In particular, this line:

```
self._column = column
```

This should be

```
self.column = column
```

(without the underscore). Near as I can tell, `GridSearchCV` uses the `set_params` function after instantiating the transformer. Because of this, if you save any of features you pass in through `__int__` you need to use the *exact same name*.